# Angularjs datatables disappear when reloading the page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to add to use [this library](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/) in my application, but everytime the page is reloaded the entire table disappears, and I don't know why. I already searched through a lot of places, and I didn't found the solution.

This is the AngularJS code (I'm using AngularJS v1.5.11):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.retorno', ['ngRoute', 'datatables']);

app.controller('RetornoCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$window', 'myCookies', 'myApi', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', function($scope, $location, $rootScope, $window, myCookies, myApi, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
      .withOption("destroy", true);
  vm.dtColumnDefs = [];
});
```

And the template:

```
<table class="table" id="table1" datatable="ng" dt-options="vm.dtOptions">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Paciente</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Opções</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="paciente in pacientes | orderBy: 'data_prevista'" >
                        <td>
                            <img class="img-circle" ng-src="{{paciente.avatar}}" alt="{{paciente.nome}}" height="40">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="#/retorno/{{paciente.sala}}">
                            <span class="fw-semi-bold">{{paciente.nome}}</span>
                          </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs text-semi-muted">
                            <span class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{{paciente.data_prevista | amDateFormat:"DD/MM/YYYY"}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs text-semi-muted">
                            <a href="#/retorno/{{paciente.sala}}" class="btn btn-primary mb-xs mr-md">Gravar retorno</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: You should never use jQuery on AngularJS/Angular apps. These apps came to replace jQuery. if you want a data table with pure angular take a look to Angular Material, PrimeNG, MDBootstrap etc

Comment: @PatricioVargas, rubbish. Programming is about solving problems and using the best tool for the job,  There is absolutely nothing wrong by using the angular directives for jQuery DataTables.  Among the "alternatives" you mention none are even remote to DT in speed and features. And as a side note: MDBootstrap is heavily dependent on jQuery :)

Comment: Two things immediately come to mind: **1**) Why use `.withOption("destroy", true)` that should ever never be needed, remove that **2**) Why use `orderBy: 'data_prevista'`, remove that. You should set default order by code, if you want to order on anything else but actual content in the columns you can use `data-order` attributes or a hidden column.

Comment: @davidkonrad Nope that's not true. MDB  has a part that is just pure angular, one for vue and one for jquery. I'm just saying, tools were invented to get away from jQuery. best developers in angular don't use jQuery and that's a fact. with primeng you can accomplish a looooot take a look to their docs

Comment: Also, if you have the option to stop using AngularJS and go for Angular..do so too. Angular is way better than AngularJS, but sometimes that's the tool we have to use for work

Comment: AngularJS wont be suported in 3 years. https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c

Comment: @PatricioVargas, I dont like jQuery either, actually dislike it, and I have never said using jQuery is recommendable - but it is pure nonsense that people should use inferior tools or change platform / framework or should rewrite their entire codebase, just because *you* dont like jQuery or *you* think there is "better" alternatives. jQuery 1.2 is exactly as good as it was +10 years ago. AngularJS is exactly as good as it was 3 years ago and so on. And if you are not in dare need of anything fancy, you are good with those.

Comment: @davidkonrad I actually love jQuery. Why would you add jQuery when you can do everything with just pure AngularJS or Angular + a component library. if Datatable library was so unique, people would be using with Angular apps...but they don't because there are tools that can accomplish the same without using jQuery

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-we-should-not-use-jQuery-in-AngularJS# :) It's all over google

Comment: @PatricioVargas, "*AngularJS wont be supported in 3 years*", and so what? I'll bet something completely different and far "better" than Angular has emerged in 3 years anyway :) Besides that, if I should abandon AngularJS in a project I would not have Angular 2-7 (or 8,9,10..?) in mind as the obvious choice, but rather Vue or React ...I would not start a new project in AngularJS either.

Comment: what do yo mean so what? you obviously don't think about code maintainability. Yes something better will come...and there are already better things like ReasonReact.. but Why would you use a tool (angular js) that even google thinks it sucks. That's why they came out with Angular

Comment: @PatricioVargas, people *do* use jQuery DataTables in angular 2,3,4,5,6 as well -> **https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started** There are several questions here on SO each and every day. The development followed the versions, and support for 1.x has completely stopped. But that doesnt matter, there were not much left to accomplish. Remember, it is just a wrapper for the underlying jQuery plugin, and it is not more complicated than people can fork and maintain their own version.

Comment: Did you look at the npm? it says supported for AngularJS it doesn't say angular, again AngularJS is going way. People who are using angularjs is because they are maintaining code  or just following what their job told them too

Comment: It all come from your "*You should never use jQuery on AngularJS/Angular apps*". **Wrong**, it is not recommendable, but it is more recommendable than to not use a better tool, just because of a religious commandment. Thats all.

Comment: And it uses jquery..where you can find all over the internet why not to use jquery in the first place and specially not with another framework like angular. People who use it need to stop

Comment: Did you look at the link? It is certainly a Angular-project, and has been that for years. Trust me, I am #2 on the DT tag and helped a lot of people with their struggles in AngularJS and Angular regarding DT. Yes, it uses jQuery, because jQuery DataTables uses jQuery. Like everything that uses bootstrap is using jQuery, because bootstrap is using jQuery ..Well. Over and out.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery and AngularJS when people tell them to do not use it. Sure you are the #2 in dt questions. Congrats! but that doesn't mean it needs to be combined jquery with Angular. This is not coming from me, this comes from this hispter genius kids that develop all this cool frameworks

Comment: Hey @PatricioVargas, not to be offensive, but it seems to me you really not understand. Yes, we should discourage for using jQuery, and jQuery is a very bad idea if you are using AngularJS or Angular, but in the case of jQuery DataTables there is actually not a better tool, so it is fine to use the directives that wraps the jQuery plugin into something meaningful. So, in fact, you are not *using* jQuery, you are using a wrapper that facilitates an oldschool library or tool. And that is OK. That is not a call for using `$('#id').text('something')` which would be really bad along with Angular.

Comment: I have been in the industry for almost 30 years.  I have seen it all. It is more or less "business as usual" that you have to had "fallbacks" or "misuse" when new technologies come around and you still have a better "oldschool" solution on the hand you need to use. There are still people playing around with ActiveX or flash, and incorporate it in their new fancy angular or react projects. I was once a delphi-programmer, when the language and codebase shifted a lot of people used a lot of energy to preserve their old components. Programming is not religion or commandments, it is practial.

Comment: @davidkonrad it's not about me not understanding it's just different point of view and how we are exposed to the technology, I have been programming for 10 years, go to a conferences once a month to stay up to date with, have taken a lot of courses and got a lot of certifications on newer technologies. Maybe in the USA we do things differently that other places in the world

Comment: but better according to who? different points of views or needs. I read their docs and I didn't see anything that tables in PrimeNG couldn't do.